# Conditions for existence of maximal basis elements contained in an open set?

Tags: general-topology

Given a point $x$, a local basis $\mathcal{B}_x$ of $x$ and an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$, under what conditions does there exist a maximal basis element in $U$?

If I set:

$$M=\{B\in \mathcal{B}_x~:~B\subseteq U\}$$

Then by Zorn's Lemma, if given a chain $B_1\subset B_2\subset B_3 \dots$ I can find an upper bound for that chain in $M$, then there exists a maximal basis element contained in $U$. The problem is, under which conditions will I be able to find such an upper bound? The union of all elements in the chain will not necessarily be a basis element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want that to hold for every open nbhd $U$ of $x$, you’re requiring precisely that the partial order $\langle\mathscr{B}_x,\supseteq\rangle$ be [well-founded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-founded_relation). It’s hard to say much more than that in general, since it depends so much on the specific details of the base.

In some cases it’s very easy to ensure that we have local base with the desired property. If $X$ is first countable at $x$, for instance, we can start with any countable local base $\{U_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$, let $B_n=\bigcap_{k\le n}U_k$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$ to get a nested base $\mathscr{B}_x=\{B_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$; clearly $\mathscr{B}_x$ has the desired property.

In fact, every local base at a point contains a local base with the desired property. The proof that I’ll sketch uses transfinite recursion to construct one.

> Let $\mathscr{U}_0$ be a local base at a point $x\in X$. Say that open sets $U$ and $U$ are *incomparable* if $U\nsubseteq V$ and $V\nsubseteq U$. Let $\mathscr{B}_0=\varnothing$, let $\mathscr{L}_0$ be a maximal pairwise incomparable subset of $\mathscr{U}_0$, let $\mathscr{B}_1=\mathscr{L}_0$, and let
>
> $$\mathscr{U}_1=\{U\in\mathscr{U}_0\setminus\mathscr{B}_0:\exists B\in\mathscr{B}_0(U\subseteq B)\}\;;$$
>
> clearly $\mathscr{B}_0\cup\mathscr{U}_1$ is a base at $x$ whose maximal elements are the members of $\mathscr{B}_0$. Recursively construct families $\mathscr{L}_\eta$, $\mathscr{U}_\eta$, and $\mathscr{B}_\eta$ as follows.
>
> - If $\eta$ is a limit ordinal, let $\mathscr{B}_\eta=\bigcup_{\xi<\eta}\mathscr{B}_\xi$ and $\mathscr{U}_\eta=\bigcap_{\xi<\eta}\mathscr{U}_\xi$, and let $\mathscr{L}_\eta$ be a maximal pairwise incomparable subset of $\mathscr{U}_\eta$.
> - If $\eta=\xi+1$, let $\mathscr{B}_\eta=\mathscr{B}_\xi\cup\mathscr{L}_\xi$, and let $$\mathscr{U}_{\eta+1}=\{U\in\mathscr{U}_\eta\setminus\mathscr{B}_\eta:\exists B\in\mathscr{B}_\eta(U\subseteq B)\}\;,$$ and let $\mathscr{L}_\eta$ be a maximal pairwise incomparable subset of $\mathscr{U}_\eta$.
>
> At some point the construction must halt because $\mathscr{U}_\eta=\varnothing$. Since $\mathscr{B}_\xi\cup\mathscr{U}_\xi$ is a base at $x$ for each $\xi\le\eta$, $\mathscr{B}_\eta$ is a local base at $x$.
>
> Suppose that $B_0,B_1\in\mathscr{B}_\eta$ are such that $B_0\subsetneqq B_1$. By construction there are $\xi_0,\xi_1<\eta$ such that $B_i\in\mathscr{L}_{\xi_i}$ for $i=0,1$, and the construction ensures that $\xi_1<\xi_0$. Thus, any chain
>
> $$B_0\subsetneqq B_1\subsetneqq B_2\subsetneqq\ldots$$
>
> in $\mathscr{B}_\eta$ must be finite, as desired.